Google AppEngine Custom Runtime Java + Maven Project
As per the below Google document, I am trying to use the Custom Runtime for using Java & maven projects. Below is the dockerfile I am using it for deploying my code with custom runtime and I got below error. Please help to fix this issue.
URL:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build
DockerFile:
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/target/rbr*.jar /app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app/rbr.jar

Got below Error,
Step #1: Step 2/8 : COPY src /home/app/src
Step #1: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src: file does not exist
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

